# matplotlib 2.0 doesn't produce plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just upgraded to matplotlib 2.0 via

```
sudo -H pip install -U matplotlib
```

Now, [the simple example](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

doesn't produce a plot anymore.

I don't know where to start debugging this. Any hints?

Comment: give [this](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) a read.

Comment: if you had previously set your backend via your matplotlibrc, the default location has changed to `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. You might check that your `matplotlibrc` is being read in correctly, and that the backend is set  to what you expect

Comment: Indeed, the backend in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc` is set to `agg` (never changed that). Setting it to `TkAgg` produces a plot, and is in fact the only option that works.

Comment: This might be a build problem with the wheels, can you report this upstream?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually [a matplotlib bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7874) which is now resolved.